# Drumroll sound not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, login, login-screen

Whenever I login into my Ubuntu system, I don't hear the welcome drumroll sound effect, even though I get to hear it if I try to close Firefox. All other sounds are working. I used to hear it earlier, but now it has suddenly stopped. What could be the possible root cause and its solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greeter is using a different sound setting to that of your normal login session. It is possible you accidentally lower or muted the audio in the login screen. Try increasing the volume while you are at the greeter login screen and reboot the system?

PS: If you are on a laptop, you may have to increase it via your hardware volume key at the login prompt.

Comment: You're right. Greeter volume was low. Had to increase it using volume slider on top right corner. That solved the problem. Thanks for answering.